# Cannot select single item from already selected items in table view with pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, tableview

I am playing with the model/view programming with pyqt to try to understand it.
My problem is that when I try si select in item from the already selected group of items the onSelection changed event does not trigger, and the selection behaviour becomes weird. (Not only cannot select items from previously selected butn also contiguous selections take place...).

If I comment the def data(self, _index, role=Qt.DisplayRole): method I get the behaviour I want, so I guess I am missing something with the way the data is populated in the table. But I cannot populate data in the table if this is commented (Hello :)).

I tried to handle it with the onMouseClick event and with the selection behaviour with no sucess.
The selection behaviour I want can be found also in this example:
https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/Reading%20selections%20from%20a%20selection%20model

Find below my code, which might be a bit messy as I am making just some trials (sorry for that).
Any comment will be much appreciatted, many thanks.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTableView, QAbstractItemView
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QAbstractTableModel, Qt, QModelIndex, QItemSelection, QItemSelectionModel, QAbstractItemModel

class myTableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, rows, columns, parent=None, *args):
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent, *args)
        self.rowCount = rows
        self.columnCount = columns
        self.table_data = [[None] * columns for _ in range(rows)]
        self.unselectedItems = []

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return self.rowCount

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return self.columnCount

    def flags(self, index):
        return Qt.ItemIsEditable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable

    def data(self, _index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole and _index.isValid():
            row = _index.row()
            column = _index.column()
            item = _index.internalPointer()
            if item is not None:
                print(item)
            value = self.table_data[row][column]
            # print('value returned: ' + str(value) + ' row: ' + str(row) + ' col: ' + str(column))
            return value
        else:
            return None

    def setData(self, _index, value, role=Qt.EditRole):
        if role == Qt.EditRole and _index.isValid():
            # print(_index.row())
            # self.arraydata[index.row()] = [value]
            # print('Return from rowCount: {0}'.format(self.rowCount(index)))
            row = _index.row()
            column = _index.column()
            self.table_data[row][column] = value
            self.dataChanged.emit(_index, _index)
            return True
        return QAbstractTableModel.setData(self, index, value, role)

    def updateSelection(self, selected, deselected):
        selectedItems = selected.indexes()
        for _index in selectedItems:
            _text = f"({_index.row()}, {_index.column()})"
            self.setData(_index, _text)
        del selectedItems[:]
        self.unselectedItems = deselected.indexes()
        for _index in self.unselectedItems:
            _text = "previous selection"
            self.setData(_index, _text)
            print('unselected item: ' + str(_index))


class myTableView(QTableView):
    def __init__(self, rowCount, columnCount, model):
        super().__init__()
        self.rowCount = rowCount
        self.columnCount = columnCount
        self.model = model
        self.setModel(model)
        self.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(tblModel.updateSelection)
        self.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.ContiguousSelection)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            selectedItems = self.selectedIndexes()
            allIndexes = []
            for i in range(self.rowCount):
                for j in range(self.columnCount):
                    allIndexes.append(self.model.index(i, j))
            # print('all indexes appended')
            indexesToClear = [_index for _index in allIndexes if
                              _index not in selectedItems and _index not in self.model.unselectedItems]
            for _index in indexesToClear:
                valueFromIndex = str(self.model.data(_index, Qt.DisplayRole))
                if valueFromIndex == "previous selection":
                    self.model.setData(_index, "")

    # def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    #     if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
    #         self.selectionModel().reset()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
tblModel = myTableModel(8, 4, app)  # create table model
tblView = myTableView(8, 4, tblModel)
topLeft = tblModel.index(0, 0, QModelIndex())
bottomRight = tblModel.index(5, 2, QModelIndex())

selectionMode = tblView.selectionModel()
selection = QItemSelection(topLeft, bottomRight)
selectionMode.select(selection, QItemSelectionModel.Select)

# set selected indexes text to selection
indexes = selectionMode.selectedIndexes()

for index in indexes:
    text = str(index.row()) + str(index.column())
    tblModel.setData(index, text, role=Qt.EditRole)

tblView.show()
app.exec()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior is erratic also because you didn't call the base class implementation of `mouseReleaseEvent`, which does some operations required to correctly update the selection, including deselecting the previously selected items except the current/new one (but the behavior can change according to the view's `selectionMode`).
Also, consider that the selectionChanged signal of the selection model only emits the *changes*: if an item was already selected when the selection changes, it will **not** be listed in the `selected` list of the signal argument.

In order to access the full list of selected items, you'll need to call the selectedIndexes() of the view, or its selection *model*.

```
class myTableView(QTableView):
    def __init__(self, model):
        super().__init__()
        # no need for these
        # self.rowCount = rowCount
        # self.columnCount = columnCount

        # NEVER overwrite existing class property names!
        # self.model = model

        self.setModel(model)
        self.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(self.updateSelection)
        self.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.ContiguousSelection)

    def updateSelection(self, selected, deselected):
        selectedIndexes = self.selectedIndexes()
        for row in range(model.rowCount()):
            for column in range(model.columnCount()):
                _index = model.index(row, column)
                if _index in selectedIndexes:
                    _text = f"({_index.row()}, {_index.column()})"
                elif _index in deselected:
                    _text = "previous selection"
                else:
                    _text = ""
                model.setData(_index, _text)
```

I also removed the rowCount and columnCount arguments for the table init, as it's redundant (and prone to errors if you change the model size): their values only depend on the model's own size, and you should access them only through it.

Finally, you should *never* overwrite existing class attributes; other than the `self.model` I commented out above, this also goes for `self.rowCount` and `self.columnCount` you used in the model (which also doesn't make much sense, as the public methods would return the methods themselves, causing recursion).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems quite right to move the updateSelection to the myTableView class and use the model as an argument. But by doing that I cannot access the model in the updateSelection method. I get: for row in range(self.model.rowCount()):
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'rowCount'

Comment: @RustyBucketBay like all properties and almost all variables of PyQt objects (except for special cases, such as QStyleOption variables), [`model`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#model) is not a "python property", but has to be accessed as a function; just call `self.model()`.

Comment: I tried to add this model = self.model(), with all the options of parenthesis in model() and rowCount(), also removing and incluiding the self. I cannot access the model argument. Sorry for my ineptitude, can you please provide the full working script in the answer? thanks in advance

Comment: Solved. My fault. Thanks for the answer and all the surrounding explanations. That was very usefull. I take the chance to ask, how can I know the default class properties that should not be overwritten?? (I looked up in the documentation and with the multiple inheritance it is not clear for me). I mean, regarding what you told regarding the model of a tableView, that should not be overwriten because its a class property

Comment: No problem! About the naming issue, unfortunately you can only get it from experience. Start by learning the base class functions and properties (which is always useful), most importantly QObject and QWidget, then remember that you can always read the "List of all members, including inherited members" link that appears on top of each Qt class description. Luckily, Qt has a very descriptive and consistent naming convention, so, in most cases, if you end up with naming something that seems "so obvious that it should be already there", it probably is :-)